# Ableton impulse drum rack switch

Tags: drums, ableton-live, samples

I like to use the preset racks in Ableton Impulse. The problem is I for the life of me cannot figure out how to switch the positions of the drum samples. Say I wanted to have the kick drum in 3rd position rather than 1st position? Dragging won't work... anyone know a simple way to say, switch the kick with the hat or whatever?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the samples from the browser on the left to the positions you want? Also, if you have Live Intro I'm pretty sure you *can't* change the samples or positions of the samples.

Comment: sure, that works, but I'm trying to stick with the samples currently in the preset. I just want to change their positions.... Why go look for it in the browser when it's right there in the preset?

Answer (score 1):

Well. I have Ableton Live 9 Suite and I just dragged one drum rack position to another one and it swapped the samples between those two positions.

From the [Ableton Live 9 PDF manual](https://cdn2-resources.ableton.com/80bA26cPQ1hEJDFjpUKntxfqdmG3ZykO/static/manual/pdf/L9Manual_EN.0f97a0bd6041.pdf) (page 275):

> Dragging a pad to another pad swaps the note mapping between the pads. This means that any MIDI clips triggering the affected notes will now play the “wrong“ sounds — although this might be exactly what you want. ALT / CMD-dragging one pad to another will layer any chains from both pads in a nested Instrument Rack.